# ** Error in `./build/minmax': free(): invalid next size (fast) - std::vector

Tags: c++, free, glibc

I know that the problem *free (): invalid next size (fast)* has been a general mistake found here on stackoverflow. But, I've been looking for anwsers about the problem and I didn't find anything like I got in my code.

Unfortunately, I can't post all the code. So, I'll give you all of the necessary code. I hope someone can help.

```
void functionA (
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> & paths,
    std::vector<int> & bases,
    stream_t & stream,
    rca::Network & network)
{

     //before loop I do some things...
     for (auto m : stream.m_group.getMembers ()) {
        int b = bases[m];
        int id = sources[b];
        rca::Path p (paths[m]);

        //here I do some other things...

     }
     // and after the loop I do more things...
}
```

The function **functionA** is invoked inside a loop and the variable *paths* is created and passed to functionA.

At the second iteration I got the error.

So, it's funny because all the posts I read talk about allocation and deallocation of memory. But, in my situation I don't do it...

I've created another function to simulate this behavior - **teste**:

```
void teste (std::vector<std::vector<int>> & paths,
    stream_t & stream)
{
    for (auto m : stream.m_group.getMembers ()) {
        rca::Path p (paths[m]);
        cout << p << endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, both functions has the code to access the position of paths and get the vector stored there. But, the code  cracks when it is invoked at the second iteration when I will create **paths** again on the main loop...

The main loop is:

```
  for(auto&& group : m_streams) {

      //some code cames before here

      //the code cracks here after first iteration
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> paths;

      functionA (paths, ...); 

      //if a replace functionA and use teste, the code works...
      //teste(paths, ...)
  }
```

So, the question is: Why the code cracks in the main loop when I'll create the **paths** variable at the second iteration(when I use **functionA** instead **teste**)?

Since, this variable is temporary and its duration is for the entire iteration only.

Comment: "Invalid next size" indicates a memory corruption bug. Memory corruption bugs often cause apparently nonsensical behavior, and the point where the symptoms manifest is almost never the point where the root cause lies. Trying to figure out the symptoms is a waste of time. You should do as is suggested in the other questions regarding this error message: apply `valgrind` to locate the true cause of the problem.

Comment: I tried valgrind and gdb, but the error wasn't too much clear to me... Valgrind and gdb indicates a specific place at the code...

So, I put the code of the function __functionA__ in the main loop of the programa, and it works fine! I keep looking for answer...

Thank you

Comment: You can ask a new question about how to interpret `valgrind` output.  Please provide the **complete, unedited** text of the **very first** error message it produces (this will look something like the section of http://pastebin.com/6AJnFWUH highlighted in yellow).  The "at ..." part of that is a stack trace; there will probably be several lines of it.  Look for the first entry naming a function that you wrote, and include the complete source code of that function as well.